# Android SDK not building

Tags: android, linux, react-native, gradle

I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I am learning react-native.

Instead of installing Android Studio, I have installed Genymotion as my android emulator for testing purposes, and installed the Android SDK using `sudo apt-get install android-sdk`

After installing the react and react native tools, I created a new react-native project and tried to run it without touching any code yet, and I have the following error

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 863 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Observed package id 'build-tools;debian' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/27.0.1' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian')
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary SDK licenses using SDK Manager: "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses". Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/arilanto/Documents/srcs/native/rdrxn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/arilanto/Documents/srcs/native/rdrxn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
    at then.result (/home/arilanto/Documents/srcs/native/rdrxn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The error message suggests me using `/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` but there is no such file or symlink

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 sept. 25 10:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 sept. 25 10:11 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   12 mars  11  2019 e2fsck -> /sbin/e2fsck
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mars  11  2019 fsck.ext4 -> /sbin/fsck.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mars  11  2019 mkfs.ext4 -> /sbin/mkfs.ext4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 mars  11  2019 resize2fs -> /sbin/resize2fs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 mars  11  2019 screenshot2 -> ../../../../bin/screenshot2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   13 mars  11  2019 tune2fs -> /sbin/tune2fs
```

Can I complete this android-sdk installation by copying files from someone who installed Android Studio on their ubuntu or should I install Android Studio altogether and change my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, also you can download them from google's site, or just reinstall sdk when download "all-in-one" android studio package. Also take a look at folder (if it exist) `/usr/lib/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin`. You have wrong/uncompleted installation. If someone's computer run deb linux distribution and have the similar processor (for example, you're both use Intel), you can just copy files.

Comment: I downloaded the SDK command line tools from Android Studio's website, extracted the archive, copied the files into `usr/lib/android-sdk/tools`, gave ownership of that folder to my regular user so I can use those commands without `sudo`